# Картинка удалятся только после обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Проблема в том что картинка удалятся только после обновления страницы а должна удался без обновления страницы с помощью ajax код js проверял в отдельном файле все работает в консоле  одна ошибка.

```
$query_img = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM uploads_images WHERE products_id='$id'");

If (mysqli_num_rows($query_img) > 0)
{

$result_img = mysqli_fetch_array($query_img);
do
{
if  (strlen($result_img["image"]) > 0 && file_exists("../uploads_images/".$result_img["image"]))
{
$img_path = '../uploads_images/'.$result_img["image"];
$max_width = 100; 
$max_height = 110; 
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path); 
$ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
$ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
$ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 

$width = intval($ratio*$width); 
$height = intval($ratio*$height);  

}else
{
$img_path = "./images/noimages.png";
$width = 90;
$height = 70;
}
echo ' 
 <li id="del'.$result_img["id"].'" >
 <img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" title="'.$result_img["image"].'" />
 <a class="del-img" img_id="'.$result_img["id"].'" ></a>        
 </li>
  ';  

}while ($result_img = mysqli_fetch_array($query_img));
}
```

/////////

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
include("../include/db_connect.php"); 

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads_images/".$_POST["title"];

        if (file_exists($path))
        {  
          unlink($path);
          $delete = mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM uploads_images WHERE id = '{$_POST["id"]}'"); 
          echo "delete";   
        }
        else
        {
           echo "delete"; 
           $delete = mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM uploads_images WHERE id = '{$_POST["id"]}'");  
        }

}
?>
```

///////

```
$('.del-img').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    var img_id = $(this).attr("img_id");
    var title_img = $("#del"+img_id+" > img").attr("title");

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./actions/delete-gallery.php",
  data: "id="+img_id+"&title="+title_img,
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) { 
  if (data == "delete")
  {
     $("#del"+img_id).fadeOut(300);
  }
                          }

});

 })
```

Comment: ммм какие сочные, прямые $_POST данные в базу

Comment: "Казнить нельзя помиловать". Какое милый и информативный вопрос. В нем сообщения об ошибке с указанием имени файла `edit_product.php` и 3 (три, Карл!) различных листинга без идентификации. Скажите, @Aleksandr, Вы действительно думаете, что тут всем интересно угадывать, какой из 3 листингов является файлом с именем `edit_product.php`? И вообще, либо 1-й листинг неполон, либо проблема в нем - именно на первой строчке файла возникает ошибка, а там даже тэга `<?php` нет, не то что открытия соединения с базой.